# Iframe src changed with Javascript not loading with Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, iframe, embed

How is it possible to load the game with javascript on chrome?

Javascript:

```
document.getElementById('game').src = "www.example.com";
```

Using IFRAME:

```
 <iframe src="/games/game.html" id="game"  
 style="display:block;margin:0 auto;" width="100%" height="100%" 
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" 
 mozallowfullscreen="true" ></iframe>
```

Or Flash:

```
 <embed src="/games/game.swf" id="game" quality="high" 
 pluginspage="http://www.macromedia.com/shockwave/download/index.cgi?
 P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" 
 width="100%" height="100%">
```

Comment: have you tried changing the relative path to  "./games/game.html"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check This [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/x75cb0uq/)

It does the trick with jquery.

```
$("#click").click(function(){
$("#game").attr("src","https://jsfiddle.net/user");
});
```

HTML

```
<span id="click">X</span>
<iframe src="https://jsfiddle.net/user/login/" id="game"  
 style="display:block;margin:0 auto;" width="100%" height="100%" 
 frameborder="0" allowfullscreen="true" webkitallowfullscreen="true" 
 mozallowfullscreen="true" ></iframe>
```

You might have some problems with your path so you might also need to check the console for errors.